# ggvis: How can I plot abline when x variable is categorical?

Tags: r, ggvis

I've searched for some solutions here but only found it for the case when x variable is numeric. So, for example, I have this dataset:

```
read.table(text="         bias           scenery algorithm treatment
 0.0038245022 pi10_40_cens35_40   Method1        T0
 0.0004553608 pi10_40_cens35_40   Method1        T1
 0.0217874958 pi10_40_cens35_40   Method2        T0
 0.0132069964 pi10_40_cens35_40   Method2        T1
 0.0135420058 pi10_40_cens35_40   Method4        T0
 0.0157829608 pi10_40_cens35_40   Method4        T1
 0.0230633621 pi10_40_cens35_40   Method3        T0
 0.0199919247 pi10_40_cens35_40   Method3        T1
 0.0751254422 pi10_40_cens60_65   Method1        T0
 0.0678869679 pi10_40_cens60_65   Method1        T1
 0.1037620465 pi10_40_cens60_65   Method2        T0
 0.0819120457 pi10_40_cens60_65   Method2        T1
 0.0893472639 pi10_40_cens60_65   Method4        T0
 0.0825019605 pi10_40_cens60_65   Method4        T1
 0.1031913181 pi10_40_cens60_65   Method3        T0
 0.1149319836 pi10_40_cens60_65   Method3        T1
 0.0048517692 pi20_30_cens35_40   Method1        T0
 0.0079070239 pi20_30_cens35_40   Method1        T1
 0.0203992390 pi20_30_cens35_40   Method2        T0
 0.0197634214 pi20_30_cens35_40   Method2        T1
 0.0142908113 pi20_30_cens35_40   Method4        T0
 0.0197736578 pi20_30_cens35_40   Method4        T1
 0.0216825265 pi20_30_cens35_40   Method3        T0
 0.0232048669 pi20_30_cens35_40   Method3        T1
 0.0576654516 pi20_30_cens60_65   Method1        T0
 0.0629337504 pi20_30_cens60_65   Method1        T1
 0.0954706388 pi20_30_cens60_65   Method2        T0
 0.0926100594 pi20_30_cens60_65   Method2        T1
 0.0793831867 pi20_30_cens60_65   Method4        T0
 0.0866745996 pi20_30_cens60_65   Method4        T1
 0.1020244131 pi20_30_cens60_65   Method3        T0
 0.1090028420 pi20_30_cens60_65   Method3        T1", 
           header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> tbl_sample
```

The plot that I have interest (without the abline) is obtained by:

```
tbl_sample %>%
  group_by(algorithm) %>% 
  ggvis(~scenery,~bias, fill=~algorithm,  shape=~treatment) %>% 
  add_legend("fill", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 20))) %>% 
  add_legend("shape", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 120))) %>%
  add_axis("y",title="bias") %>%
  layer_points()
```

Static version:

[image]

Now then, how can I obtain exactly the same graph but with an dashed horizontal line on y=0?

Comment: try `geom_hline(yintercept=0,lty=1)` or if necessary `geom_hline(yintercept=0,lty=1,aes(group=1))` ?

Comment: oops.  `aes(group=1)` might still work?

Comment: This looks like the best answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggvis/csYp7r3BwSA

Comment: Thanks for editing the dataset and inserting the plot! I tried something with layer_paths(), but the best thing I could do with x defined this way was creating an line beginning on 'pi10_40_cens_35_40' and ending on 'pi20_30_cens60_65'. But in this case, I need the whole line beyond this interval.

Comment: Unfortunately, until the RStudio team hunkers down to rly focus on ggvis in 2016, the best you're going to be able to do is precisely what you just commented (which is spot on):  `layer_paths(~x, ~y, stroke:="red", data=data.frame(x=c("pi10_40_cens35_40", "pi20_30_cens60_65"), y=c(0.00 ,0.00)))` (though perhaps others who use ggvis more than i do might have alternatives)

Comment: have to say that this sort of thing (and not really needing web-friendly/dynamics graphics) is a lot of the reason I haven't switched away from ggplot yet ...

Comment: BTW, it might be helpful if you provide links to the (numeric-only) solutions you found elsewhere ..

Comment: it's definitely one reason I've built widgets for metricsgraphics and taucharts, but hadley has said in two presentations recently that ggvis is #1 priority in 2016, so it may get the full-on ggplot2-goodness next year. i ggplot2 as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with ggplot2 syntax (been on a ggvis class trying to escape learning ggplot2 haha)... Any hint to get the same plot using ggplot2? 

About the numeric-only solutions, I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584666/draw-a-line-with-intercept-and-slope-in-ggvis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments convo, the best you'll (probably) be able to do with ggvis is to add:

```
layer_paths(~x, ~y, stroke:="red", 
            data=data.frame(x=c("pi10_40_cens35_40", "pi20_30_cens60_65"),
                            y=c(0.00 ,0.00)))
```

for:

[image]

You can do what you want in ggplot2 though:

```
library(ggplot2)  

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=tbl_sample,
                      aes(x=scenery, y=bias, color=algorithm, shape=treatment))
gg <- gg + geom_hline(yintercept=0.00, color="red", linetype="dashed")
gg <- gg + labs(x="Scenery", y="Bias", title=NULL)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I'll use definitely this. Guess it's still worth learning ggplot2 nowadays. Thank you.

Comment: is `group_by(tbl_sample, algorithm)` really necessary here ?  would just `tbl_sample` work ... ?

Comment: you're right @BenBolker. I just did a lazy copy/paste from my local ggvis lines.